# Cannot Launch Anaconda Navigator after Installing

Tags: python, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda and I've been trying to launch Anaconda Navigator but I keep getting the following error:

Main Error:
check_hostname requires server_hostname

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score -2):

After I closed "Clash for Windows" and the proxy settings, the problem went away.
Maybe u can give it a try.